# Creating a dataFrame with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have almost 20000 records in a txt file, each a dictionary in this format

```
Plan-expiry/10_160.json b'{"userId":10,"paymentTransactionId":1602348638905}'
Plan-expiry/11_161.json b'{"userId":11,"paymentTransactionId":1612587468258}'
Plan-expiry/12_162.json b'{"userId":12,"paymentTransactionId":1623589572478}'
Plan-expiry/13_163.json b'{"userId":13,"paymentTransactionId":1634682580747}'
Plan-expiry/14_164.json b'{"userId":14,"paymentTransactionId":1642469647427}'
Plan-expiry/15_165.json b'{"userId":15,"paymentTransactionId":1652460745327}'
```

From this I want to create a dataframe which has two columns - userId and paymentTransactionId
How can I achieve this in pandas?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide an [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one way:

```
df = pd.read_csv(<you text file path here>)
df = df.pop(df.columns[-1]).str.strip('b\'').apply(eval).apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: Great!! This works, but somehow it does not when paymentTransactionId is having one value as 1573578953578. Can you tell why? Please!

Comment: @PratitiBera Working for me can you add the issue in your question so that I can reproduce the error?